# Assembly Mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I'm facing this error. How could I overcome this error? I am new in Entity Framework. Any help would be very much appreciated..

> Assembly 'HRMSDataAccessLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' uses      'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' which has    a
>   higher version than referenced assembly 'EntityFramework,
>   Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Comment: You are referencing an older version of Entity Framework than what is required by HRMSDataAccessLayer.

Comment: How can I change the version of Entity Framework?  In properties file Target .NET Framework is given 4.5 @ryrich

Comment: EF version 4.4? I can't even find this version on NuGet

Comment: I updated both Entity Framework version and it worked just fine. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the reference for the higher version in your solution.

```
Assembly 'HRMSDataAccessLayer, .. uses 'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, ...
which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0,
```

You need to add the reference for the Entity framework version 4.4.0.0

Hope that helps.

Comment: sorry for my inability but could please tell me how to add reference for the higher version in my solution?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx you would find this useful. please scroll down for basics.